# Excel Percentage Conversion

Tags: excel

I have a column in my excel spreadsheet in which percentages are listed such as 10.7%, 4.5% is there a way that I can remove the percentage signs while keeping the numbers the same? I would like the number to look like 10.7 instead of 10.7% and 4.5 instead of 4.5%

Comment: Sure. Remove the percent formatting, and multiply each value by 100.

Comment: Have to bear in mind that the actual numbers were 0.107, 0.045 etc. so need to divide by 100 in any arithmetic that's done on them after they're multiplied by 100. No way that I know of removing the % sign and still getting them displayed as percentages.

Comment: There is a work-around here which does answer the question http://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/297038-custom-formats-removing-percentage-symbol.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

- Assuming you have your percentages in cell A1, in cell B1 type `=NUMBERVALUE(A1)*100`
- Copy B1 and paste it down as far as the rows in A have the percentages
- Right click entire column B -> Copy
- Right click entire column B -> Paste Options Values
- Remove column A

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to change the underlying values:-

- Highlight the range of numbers
- In the alignment panel, turn on Wrap Text
- In custom formats, type 100 followed by <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>J</kbd> followed by %.

See [This reference](http://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/297038-custom-formats-removing-percentage-symbol.html)